# Script does not enter in else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table on the right of my page( with `id="efficacia"`). I wrote this `JS` script in order to shift left/right clicking on it

**JavaScript**

```
$("#efficacia").click(function() {
    var posizione = $("#efficacia").position();

    if(posizione.right != 0) {
        $(this).animate({
            right: '0'
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        $(this).animate({
            right: '-202'
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
#efficacia {
    position: fixed;
    right: -202px;
    top: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

My script works well for the first "click", then when I click again it does not shitf on the right of 202px. It looks like that function does not enter in else statemet.

Comment: try to log the value of `posizione.right` - like `console.log(posizione.right)`

Comment: It doesn't work. Script behaves in the same way

Comment: @Domenico This is not a fix, he was asking what value gets logged.

Comment: it was not a solution... you need to look at the value of `posizione.right` to see why the condition is not working... so the line I provided, logs the value to the browser's console

Comment: I have updated the code. Hope it will solve your problem well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`position`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) doesn't return a `right property`.

You can get the `right` css property so:

```
$("#efficacia").click(function() {
    var right = parseInt($(this).css('right'));

    if(right != 0) {
        $(this).animate({
            right: '0'
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        $(this).animate({
            right: '202'
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

See the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dvmm5cd2/)**.

Answer (score 3):

`position().right` does not exist. Only top and left.
http://api.jquery.com/position/

Base your condition on `left` attribute and it will work

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your code at **right: '-202'**. You have to specify **right: '-202px'**.

Here's the updated code:

```
$("#efficacia").click(function() {
   var right = $(this).css('right');

   if(right != "0px") {
       $(this).animate({
        right: '0px'
       }, 1000);
   } else {
       $(this).animate({
           right: '-202px'
       }, 1000);
   }
});
```

That's it

Comment: `position.right` doesn't exist... `position` will only give the top and left position.

Comment: Am not talking about position.right . I mentioned css property inside animate function as right:-202px where as he mentioned right:-202. Got it. And don't downvote without going through completely.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the failing units, but this answer doesn't give the (whole) solution, since `position.right` isn't valid. Test it yourself, and you'll see. Don't give an answer without going through completely ;)

Comment: Ofcouse, but this will improve solve his issue upto some extent. So, what's the need to downvote this answer.

Comment: I have updated the code. Hope it will solve your problem well.

Comment: That is a complete solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want get position of all corners then you can use `getBoundingClientRect()`. It will returns bottom, right, left, top, width and height of your div. But, of course, it will return values that starts from left corner.

```
var boundingBox = $(this).get(0).getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(boundingBox.right);
```

[Read about getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect)

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.position()` **doesn't return value for style.right.** It returns only

`Object{top: somVal, left: somVal}` 
so if u want to get the value of right then **get it from style attribute**

Eg-

```
  $("#efficacia").click(function() {
       // var posizione = $("#efficacia").position();//here right is undefined
     var right=this.style.right.replace("px", "") * 1;//fetch value of right from style
        if(right != 0) {
            $(this).animate({
                right: '0' 
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            $(this).animate({
                right: '202'
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```